# Laravel Relationship Issues : Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 tables in my application... Users Conventioners

I have users id in the conventioners table and i want to access their genders from the Users table....

I have like 10 user ids in the conventioners table and 20 users in the users table...

Please how do I access all their genders in the users table...

```
$conventioners->users()->gender
```

Conventioners is an instance of the Conventioner Model which contains a relationship **belongsToMany

Thanks alot guys

Here is my Conventioner Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Conventioner extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'conventioners';

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id','year','church_id','convention_id'
    ];

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function convention()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Convention');
    }
}
```

Here is my ConventionController method called Convention...
It retrieves the details for the current convention

```
public function convention($slug)
    {
        if(!$this->admin()) return redirect()->back();

        $convention = Convention::where('slug', $slug)->first();

        $participants = Conventioner::where('convention_id', $convention->id)->get();

        $conventioner = [];
        foreach($participants as $participant)
        {
            $thisUser = [];
            $thisUser['data'] = User::withTrashed()->where('id', $participant->user_id)->first();
            $thisUser['convention'] = $participant;
            array_push($conventioner, $thisUser);
        }

        var_dump($participants->users()->pluck('gender')->all());

        return view('dashboard/conventions/convention', [
            'convention' => $convention,
            'user' => Auth::user(),
            'conventioners' => $convention->conventioners(),
            'participants' => $conventioner
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: try `$conventioners->users->gender`

Comment: also post your models here it would help

Comment: BelongsToMany requires a pivot table. Think you may have got confused on your relationship definition.

Comment: @SapneshNaik have tried $conventioners->users->gender but it isn't working

Comment: @prime pivot table..?

Comment: Where's the model code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that users is a collection not an individual that you can call `gender` on. If you want a list of all the genders you can use the following:

```
Conventioner::where('convention_id', $convention->id)->with('users')->get()
$conventioners->pluck('users')->pluck('gender')->all();
```

This will return an array of the genders. You can read more about `pluck` [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck).

> The pluck method retrieves all of the values for a given key

Comment: Exception in Collection.php line 1564:  Property [users] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74: Method users does not exist.

Comment: Is conventioners not a Laravel collection?

Comment: $convention = Convention::where('slug', $slug)->first();

$conventioners = Conventioner::where('convention_id', $convention->id)->get();

Comment: Can you add your Conventioner model user relation to your initial question?

Comment: I have added the methods and the model

Comment: I've edited my response. Conventioners is a collection not an individual model. This should work.

Comment: QueryException in Connection.php line 647: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.conventioner_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`conventioner_id` in (1, 2) and `users`.`deleted_at` is null)

Comment: $conventioners = Conventioner::where('convention_id', $convention->id)->with('users')->get();

        $data = $conventioners->pluck('users')->pluck('gender')->all();

        var_dump($data);